# What type of database do I need?

Tags: database

I'm creating a wallpaper app on android studio. I'm assuming the best way to go about this is to pull the images from a database so that the app doesn't take up as much storage? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: A database doesn't magically make images take up less space.

Comment: you can use SQLite Database

Comment: I looking to take up less space on the phone by pulling images from a database server. Is that something I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull from an existing database or create a new one using Google’s app tool [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). Another option is to use an open source app such as Wallak to create your own custom app by modifying the code.